# Precarious Popen Piping

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I want to use `subprocess.Popen` to run a process, with the following requirements.

1. I want to pipe the `stdout` and `stderr` back to the caller of `Popen` as the process runs.
2. I want to kill the process after `timeout` seconds if it is still running.

I have come to the conclusion that a flaw in the `subprocess` API means it cannot fulfill these two requirements at the same time. Consider the following toy programs:

## chatty.py

```
while True:
    print 'Hi'
```

## silence.py

```
while True:
    pass
```

## caller.py

```
import subprocess
import time

def go(command, timeout=60):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    start = time.time()
    while proc.poll() is None:
        print proc.stdout.read(1024) # <----- Line of interest
        if time.time() - start >= timeout:
            proc.kill()
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

Consider the marked line above.

- If it is included, `go('python silence.py')` will hang forever - not for just 60 seconds - because `read` is a blocking call until either `1024` bytes or end of stream, and neither ever comes.
- If it is commented, `go('python chatty.py')` will be printing out `'Hi'` over and over, but how can it be streamed back as it is generated? `proc.communicate()` blocks until end of stream.

I would be happy with a solution that replaces requirement (1) above with "In the case where a timeout did not occur, I want to get `stdout` and `stderr` once the algorithm finishes." Even this has been problematic. My implementation attempt is below.

## speech.py

```
for i in xrange(0, 10000):
    print 'Hi'
```

## caller2.py

```
import subprocess
import time

def go2(command, timeout=60):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        if proc.poll() is not None:
            print proc.communicate()
            break
        elif time.time() - start >= timeout:
            proc.kill()
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
```

But even this still has problems. Even though `python speech.py` runs in just a couple seconds, `go2('python speech.py')` takes the full 60 seconds. This is because the call to `print 'Hi'` in `speech.py` is blocking until `proc.communicate()` is called when the process is killed. Since `proc.stdout.read` had the problem demonstrated before with `silence.py`, I'm really at a loss for how to get this working.

How can I get both the `stdout` and `stderr` and the timeout behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to setup a side-band timer to kill the process. I wrote up a program half way between chatty and silent:

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print i
    time.sleep(1)
```

And then a program to kill it early:

```
import subprocess as subp
import threading
import signal

proc = subp.Popen(['python', 'longtime.py'], stdout=subp.PIPE, 
    stderr=subp.PIPE)
timer = threading.Timer(3, lambda proc: proc.send_signal(signal.SIGINT),
    args=(proc,))
timer.start()
out, err = proc.communicate()
timer.cancel()
print proc.returncode
print out
print err
```

and it output:

```
$ python killer.py
1
10
9
8

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "longtime.py", line 6, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Your timer could be made fancier, like trying increasingly bad signals til the process completes, but you get the idea.

Comment: Looks promising. Trying this out tomorrow.